# ¿Cómo leer JSON encadenado que retorna firebase function? JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, firebase

Realicé una función con firebase la cuál retorna un JSON encadenado de todas los datos que tengo en realtime database.

Usando FETCH obtengo el JSON, pero no encuentro como acceder a un elemento en especifico y su contenido:

```
    fetch('https:')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);


    })
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El anterior código me muestra en consola el JSON siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo podría acceder al nombre del elemento 2? De antemano, muchas gracias

Comment: Por favor coloca una muestra en texto de la data que te esta regresando la petición, además de eso el código va como texto y no como imagen

Comment: A juzgar por esta linea , el objeto que te devuelve un formato json es res, no data  => .then(res => res.json())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

podrias hacerlo recorriendo con for y un contador, lo hice con un for in donde obj es el objeto obviamente y prop la propiedad, este es un ejemplo.

```
 var obj = {"efhregvfrgy":{name:"prueba"},"rjihrbgirhihrbg":{name:"prueba2"}};
 var contador=0;
 for (const prop in obj) {
      contador++;
      if(contador==2){
           var segundo=obj[prop];
           alert(segundo.name);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Gracias, así no tuve que modificar el generar keys automáticas desde mi backend

Comment: @danielm2402 de nada, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo funcional de como leer un string JSon desde Javascript usando la función `JSON.parse()`;

```
<script>
var txt = '{"name":"prueba"}'
var obj = JSON.parse(txt);
alert(obj.name);
</script>
```